# Disable key bindings in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have defined my own project nature in eclipse. This project has a specific file. For this file type I want to disable copy paste. I have already removed copy and Paste options from context menu of the file by using eclipse Activity-Pattern binding. But, still the user can do Ctrl+C and Ctrl+V from keyboard to achieve the same. Is there any way I can disable these predefined key bindings in eclipse. I would like to define such a functionality in my plugin.xml. Please help.

Comment: ..I am curious why you would want to do that. Also: in the navigator view I suspect it is still possible to copy/paste with the context menu. (edit: actually I'm not sure, but curious about that)

Comment: I am talking about project explorer view in eclipse. The file which I am talking about is actually a BPMN file. It actually contains more than few entries which serve as keys in some db tables. So I want users to use the wizard to create such a file in my project and not to do manual Copy Paste. This is the reason I want to disable copy paste.